# Magento Configurable Product DropDown - Must Change "Price Difference - +" To Actual Price

Tags: javascript, php, magento, drop-down-menu, configurable-product

I am building a Magento website for work - using CE 1.9

Would like to use Configurable products - But on the product page the drop down displays changes with the - + price differences.. We just know this will confuse all our customers so I have been asked to change the price differences to the product set price..

Or we could also just remove the `+ £xx.xx` and pricing and just display the product names.  Price refreshing when selected from drop down..

I started off looking through the Magento Admin settings but couldn't make the change.. After searching on Google I noticed other people have the same issue.. but the suggestions all seem to be out of date or not applicable to my version of Magento..

The `js/varien/product.js`  Is a possible area for a fix - but My JavaScript is having difficulty..

Have also looked at

```
js/varien/configurable.js
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Abstract.php **on line 128**
```

many different suggestions on Google but nothing seems to work..

Many thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show price of each simple product , there is already a module xalled Simple Configurable Products, here is link http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html

*[Edit]*

1. *Magento Default feature* => Or we could also just remove the + £xx.xx and pricing and just display the product names.
2. *Simple Configurable Products Module feature* => change the price differences to the product set price.. So you have choice to go. If answer helped, accept it for the community

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Krishna, the simple product prices are set to £0.00 - prices are created from inside the Configurable product Associated Products Tab.. 

Were going to have maybe 1000 configurable products so I wanted to keep the simple products usable for all items.. 

Thanks for the link - I have seen that module before - will look at it again if it can help.. not sure if it has this functionality tho..

hope than makes sense..

Also I dont want to add too many modules because we want to run this quite lean.. Would much prefer to edit the code.

Comment: 1) Magento Default feature => Or we could also just remove the + £xx.xx and pricing and just display the product names. 2) Simple Configurable Products Module feature => change the price differences to the product set price.. So you have choice to go. If answer helped, accept it for the community (editing my answer)

Comment: Hi Krishna.  

Just reading over the module text spec.. PROBLEM IS.. 

.....With this extension the price for configurable products is taken directly from the associated simple products rather than the configurable product itself.

With over 3000 products that will be Configurable.. I cant make 3 Simple product variations for each one.. We would be touching 10,000 products.. 

Is there another way?.. 

Thanks

Comment: Showing price of configurable product is Magento Default option. +/- is shown because you have added prices on "Super product attributes configuration" - on Associated Products tab of Configurable Product edit.

Comment: Ok - Finally got a fix for this problem after a whole day... js/varien/product.js  & js/varien/configurable.js comment out the str+ references on both those files..  its not the best solution maybe.. but as long as it works :)
Thanks again